# matrix spectral theorem proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know this question has already been asked but those threads weren't any help. We have real matrix $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..\lambda_n)$. The rows of $U$ are the orthonormal eigenvectors of matrix $A$ $x_1, x_2, ...x_n$. Proof that the matrix $A$ can written as $$A=\lambda_1 x_1 x_1^{T}+\lambda_2 x_2 x_2^{T}+..+\lambda_n x_n x_n^{T}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $x_1^{-1}$?

Comment: It was supposed to be a transpose "T", not inverse. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that the expression you have written is nonsense: you can't invert a vector! What you meant to write is $\lambda_1x_1x_1^T$, etc. Also, the eigenvectors are the columns, not the rows, of $U$.

Now just apply the basic definition of matrix multiplication:
$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj}$$
to the product $UDU^T$:
$$(U(DU^T))_{ij} = \sum_k U_{ik}(DU^T)_{kj} = \sum_k U_{ik}\sum_l D_{kl}U^T_{lj}.$$
$D_{kl}$ is zero unless $k=l$ in which case it is $\lambda_k$, so
$$(UDU^T)_{ij} = \sum_k U_{ik}\lambda_k U^T_{kj}$$
...can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the simplest answer is to just compute $UD U^T$ using matrix multiplication, but there is also a more conceptual answer which is very important.  The conceptual answer is more enlightening, but has more risk of being confusing.  I'll explain it both ways.

---

Here's the more conceptual explanation.

It may seem difficult to understand or visualize what $A$ does to a vector.  But, it's very easy to understand what $A$ does to a vector that belongs to an eigenspace $E_\lambda$.  $A$ simply scales that vector by $\lambda$.

This suggests a strategy for understanding $A$.  Given a vector $v$, think of $v$ as the sum of its projections onto the eigenspaces $E_{\lambda_1},\ldots,E_{\lambda_n}$:
$$
v = P_1 v + \cdots + P_n v,
$$
where $P_i v$ is the projection of $v$ onto $E_{\lambda_i}$.  It might be hard to understand what $A$ does to $v$, but it's easy to understand what $A$ does to $P_i v$, because $P_i v \in E_\lambda$.  So:
$$
Av = \underbrace{A P_1 v}_{\text{easy}} + \cdots + \underbrace{A P_n v}_{\text{easy}} = \lambda_1 P_1 v + \cdots + \lambda_n P_n v.
$$
We are almost done.  We only need to write $P_i v$ more explicitly.  How do we project $v$ onto $E_{\lambda_i}$, which is the subspace spanned by $x_i$?  We all know this projection formula.  The answer is
$$
P_i v = x_i x_i^T v.
$$
Thus, we have found that
$$
Av = \lambda_1 x_1 x_1^T v + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n x_n^T v = (\lambda_1 x_1 x_1^T + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n x_n^T)v.
$$
Because this is true for any vector $x$, it follows that
$$
A = \lambda_1 x_1 x_1^T + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n x_n^T.
$$

---

---

Now here is a different explanation, which could be summarized as "just multiply the matrices and see what you get".

First notice that $U^{-1} = U^T$, so that $A = U D U^T$.

It helps to be very comfortable with block matrix multiplication.  For example, we can write $D$ using block notation as
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 e_1 & \lambda_2 e_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n e_n \end{bmatrix},
$$
where the column vector $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector.
Now we use block multiplication:
$$
U D = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 U e_1 & \lambda_2 U e_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n U e_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 x_1 & \cdots & \lambda_n x_n \end{bmatrix}.
$$
(In the second equation we used the fact that $U e_i$ is the $i$th column of $U$, which is obvious if you have internalized the fact that multiplying a matrix by a vector gives you a linear combination of the columns of the matrix.)

It follows that
$$
UDU^T = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 x_1 & \lambda_2 x_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n x_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1^T \\ x_2^T \\ \vdots \\ x_n^T \end{bmatrix}.
$$
At this point, we use block multiplication to multiply the two matrices on the right, and we find that
$$
UDU^T = \lambda_1 x_1 x_1^T + \lambda_2 x_2 x_2^T + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n x_n^T.
$$